# How do I start an Android alarm if the user is never going to open the app?

Tags: android

I'm trying to write an app that checks a database for certain times, and sets an alarm for that day's time every day. I can't just start every alarm at once; that'd kill the phone in no time. For ease of access, I don't want the user to have to open up the app every morning and press a big red button to start the alarm up. So ideally, upon installing the app, the app should start up a procedure that activates an alarm for each day according to the database. I can figure out how to set an alarm from the database, but - unfortunately - only if they open up the app and press a button. What I need is a way for the app to set an alarm triggering it to set an alarm, and to do that without ever being opened. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean that user just install the app, but not even open it once? If so, that's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

When the user first opens the app , set an  alarm to start a service on next day morning , which will check your database and set the alarm .And the service will also set a new alarm to start itself next day morning and repeat the work .

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you can't do this, it's terrible to user's experience. after android 4.0, your app must be opened at least once, you broadcast receiver can work normally.In other words, you can do noting before user open it once.